# What is the mistake in this method for finding probability?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

A bag contains 10 black and 5 white balls. Two balls are drawn randomly one by one without replacement from the bag. If it is known that at least one ball is black then find the probability that both are black?

For the above question , I thought that since atleast one ball we already know is black then of remaining 14 balls(9 of which will be black) that ball drawn must be black so Probability = 9/14

But the correct way

A : Atleast one ball is black ,P(A)=19/21

B : Both balls are black, P(B) = 3/7

then P(B/A) = 9/19 is the correct probability.
I not able to figure out what is wrong with the first method?

Comment: This is a variant of the usual [Boy/Girl probability "paradox"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boy_or_Girl_paradox).

Comment: What is wrong with the first method is that you are conflating two different problems together.  Your answer is the answer to the question "*If it is known that very specifically the first ball pulled is black, what is the probability that the second ball is also black?*"  Which is different than the question asked here where the statement "at least one ball is black" is in reference to *either* of the balls being black but where we are not given the information about which ball it was.

Answer (score 1):

The probability that at least one ball is black = $\Pr(B)$

$$\Pr(B) = \frac{5}{15} \cdot \frac{10}{14} + \frac{10}{15} \cdot \frac{5}{14} + \frac{10}{15} \cdot \frac{9}{14} = \frac{19}{21}$$

The probability that both balls are black and at least one ball is black = The probability that both balls are black = $\Pr(E \cap B) = \frac{10}{15} \cdot \frac{9}{14}$

The probability that both balls are black *given that* at least one ball is black = $P(E|B)$

$$\Pr(E|B) = \frac{P(E \cap B)}{P(B)} = \frac{9}{19}$$

Phew ...

Comment: I know this solution but I am not able to figure out what is wrong with the first method.

Comment: You're calculating the probability that both balls are black. $\frac{10}{15} \cdot \frac{9}{14}$. The question asks for the probability that both are black IF you know that at least one is black.